# UseEffect hook in next.js is causing 2 fetch requests when I expect 1, why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, fetch-api

The following code is causing 2 requests to be made to my API with the GET endpoint.  I don't understand useEffect() enough to know where to start to debug, but I don't want to cause unneccessary strain on the services that these API endpoints will call server side.  This is because they will be calling windows servers to action delete requests in active directory etc...

```
function Ad() {
    const [data, setData] = useState(null)
    const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false)
    useEffect(() => {
        setLoading(true)
        fetch('../api/decom/ad')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                setData(data)
                setLoading(false)

                if (data.exists == true) {
                    Remove()
                    }
            })
    }, [])

    const Remove = () => {

        fetch("../api/decom/ad", { method: "DELETE" })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                var inner = ""
                if (data.removed == true) {
                    inner = `<p>Removed: ${greenCircle}</p>`
                } else {
                    inner = `<p>Removed: ${redCircle}</p>`
                }

                document.getElementById('adremoved').innerHTML = inner

            })
    }

    if (data != null  && data.exists == true) return (
        <a className={styles.card}>
            <h2>AD</h2>
            <p>Exists: { greenCircle } </p>
            <div id ="adremoved" className={styles.parent}>
                <p className={styles.child}>removed:</p>
                <div><div className={styles.loader}><div></div><div></div><div></div></div></div>
            </div>
        </a>
    )

    if (data != null && data.exists == false) return (
        <a className={styles.card}>
            <h2>AD</h2>
            <p>Exists: {redCircle} </p>
            <p>Removed:{redCircle}</p>
        </a>
        )

    if (isLoading) return (
        <a className={styles.card}>
            <h2>AD</h2>
            <div className={styles.parent}>
                <p id="adstatus" name="adstatus" className={styles.child}>Exists:</p>
                <div id="adloader"><div className={styles.loader}><div></div><div></div><div></div></div></div>
            </div>
            <p>Removed:{redCircle}</p>
        </a>
        )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const router = useRouter()
const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true)
    useEffect(() => {
       if(isLoading && router.isReady){
        fetch('../api/decom/ad')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {              
                if (data.exists == true) {
                    Remove()
                    }else{
                setData(data)                
                }
               setLoading(false)
            })
       }
    }, [isLoading])
```

Comment: This still sends 2 requests when I load the page, also when using router.query, I see that the URL says that the query is undefined, almost as if a promise hasn't resolved...

Comment: i edited code for router

Answer (score 0):

If you are using react 18, useEffect hook will run twice, that is the expected behaviour

`React 18 introduces a new development-only check to Strict Mode. This new check will automatically unmount and remount every component, whenever a component mounts for the first time, restoring the previous state on the second mount.`

https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#ensuring-reusable-state